# How do I calculate sine/cosine/tangent from CORDIC, Taylor Series, or alternative in Python?

Tags: python

I am making a library for math functions, intended to test and challenge my programming and math skills. A necessary part of this is trig: Sine, Cosine, Tangent, and derivatives/inverses, using degrees or radians.

I have spent hours searching the web for implementation of Taylor Series or CORDIC algorithm using degrees AND/OR radians, to no avail.

```py
def sin(x):
    if numerics.degrad == 'deg':
        #compute sin(x) using degrees or radians, make sure to return the result in degrees
```

Please be informed, numerics.degrad is a string value to be referenced from any function in the library or terminal. Usual values are 'deg' or 'rad'. Also, I am trying to avoid importing libraries like numpy or math.

UPDATE: I tried today(11-12-19) to emulate sine by generating a parabola which intersected one waveform. The hope was to check which waveform the angle would land on, then use the according quadratic equation. That did not work. Results in DESMOS were off by up to 0.2 units, and my python implementation was just plain wrong.

```py
# desmos implementation, where y is the output and x is the angle:
# y=0.0001234567901234(x-90)^2+1
# lays closely over a sine wave graphed with y=sin(x).

# here is my python implementation:

def sin(anglein):    #return the result of sine of the supplied angle, using the mode
    if degrad == 'deg':
        const = 0.0001234567901234
        angle = anglein
        while angle > 360:    #should return the corresponding angle within 0-360 degrees
            angle -= 360

        return((const * ((angle - 90) * (angle - 90))) + 1)
```

Comment: Pls show us what you have tried then what is the error you are getting. It is more fun if you try it. Thanks.

Comment: Your emphasis on `using degrees AND/OR radians` suggests to me that perhaps you're under the impression that the implementation would differ in any material way between these inputs. I have no trouble finding example CORDIC implementations. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) for a MATLAB implementation which takes radians as input. Why not simply port an implementation like this, and when given degree inputs, scale them by `pi/180` to get radians, and then call the radian implementation?

Comment: I do not know what to try, that's why there is nothing up there.

Comment: start with give me the the formula of taylor series that approximates sin x. If x is in radians; (let's deal with degrees later on)

Comment: Found this page regarding a Taylor Series for sine. https://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/sine_calculator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor series for the sin function is straightforward to implement. Note that any reference which gives a Taylor series for a trigonometric function will assume the input is in radians, unless specified otherwise.

```py
PI = 3.141592653589793238462643383

def sin_taylor_series(x, terms=9):
    # map x into the range -PI/2 to PI/2 for greatest accuracy
    x %= 2*PI
    if x > PI:
        x -= 2*PI
        if x < -PI/2:
            x = -PI - x
    elif x > PI/2:
        x = PI - x

    total = 0
    denominator = 1
    for i in range(1, 2*terms+2, 2):
        denominator *= i
        total += (x ** i) / denominator
        denominator *= -(i + 1)
    return total
```

At 9 terms, the max absolute error (compared with `math.sin`) is under `10 ** -15`, which is about as good as you're going to get by adding a lot of floating point numbers together.

Note that this is not a particularly efficient way of approximating the sin function.

Comment: Thank you for this! I see it works in radians, but I can convert it to degrees.

Comment: For anyone who reads this, convert any answer which is in degrees to radians. DO NOT convert the result, just use it raw, as the result of sine is a ratio, not an angle.