# How to calculate sum of terms of Taylor series of sin(x) without using inner loops or if-else?

Tags: python

1. I can't use inner loops
2. I can't use if-else

I need to compute the following series:

```
x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7! + x^9/9! ...
```

I am thinking something like the following:

```
n =1
x =0.3
one=1
fact1=1
fact2=1
term =0
sum =0
for i in range(1, n+1, 2):
    one = one * (-1)
    fact1 = fact1*i
    fact2 = fact2*i+1
    fact = fact1*fact2
    x = x * x
    term = x/fact
    sum = sum + term
```

But, I am finding hard times in keeping the multiplications of both fact and x.

Comment: "I can't use inner loops. I can't use if-else" what sort of requirements are these?!

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaking, but the pattern is [this one](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7BN%7D(-1)%5En%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2n%2B1%7D%7D%7Bn!%7D) right? Otherwise, yes I agree it's quite weird to not be able to use inner loops when you have factorials.

Comment: @BastienAntoine, hmm. But, signs are opposite in each term.

Comment: @user366312 yeah my bad, I read it too fast, corrected!

Comment: @BastienAntoine, you also have problems with n. n is odd number.

Comment: @user366312 that's why I've put the 2n+1, to make it odd

Comment: Looks like the series is infinite. Do you have a criterion for how far to go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate sine/cosine/tangent from CORDIC, Taylor Series, or alternative in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807798/how-do-i-calculate-sine-cosine-tangent-from-cordic-taylor-series-or-alternativ)

Comment: @HeapOverflow, N=30

Comment: @BastienAntoine, check the divisor n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compute a sum of terms. Each term is the previous term mutiplied by `-1 * x * x` and divided by `n * (n+1)`. Just write it:

```
def func(x):
    eps = 1e-6                   # the expected precision order
    term = x
    sum = term
    n = 1
    while True:
        term *= -x * x
        term /= (n+1) * (n+2)
        if abs(term) < eps: break
        sum += term
        n += 2
    return sum
```

Demo:

```
>>> func(math.pi / 6)
0.4999999918690232
```

giving as expected 0.5 with a precision of 10e-6

---

Note: the series is the well known development of the `sin` function...

Comment: I'd change this to use for loop with parameter n for number of terms. That way you could get rid of the if clause that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a Taylor series for sin(x)? And can you use list comprehension? With list comprehension that could be something like

```
x = 0.3
sum([ (-1)**(n+1) * x**(2n-1) / fact(2n-1) for n in range(1, numOfTerms)])
```

If you can't use list comprehension you could simply loop that like this

```
x=0.3
terms = []
for n in range(1, numberOfTerms):
  term = (-1)**(n+1)*x**(2n-1)/fact(2n-1)
  terms.append(term)

sumOfTerms = sum(terms)
```

Then calculating the factorial by recursion:

```
def fact(k):
  if (k == 1):
    return n
  else:
    return fact(k-1)*k
```

Calcualting the factorial using Striling's approximation:

```
fact(k) = sqrt(2*pi*k)*k**k*e**(-k)
```

No if-else here nor inner loops. But then there will be precision errors and need to use math lib to get the constants or get even more precision error and use hard coded values for pi and e.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! But this won't work if you keep the initial requirements to not use inner loops as you have to use them to compute the factorials

Comment: How about using recursion to calculate factorials?

Comment: Didn't think about the "can not use if-else" -rule. Need to re-think this. This is very unusual scenario with all those rules :)

Comment: Has the value of each term to be exact? If not, you could use Strilings approximation to calculate the factorial. That will cause some precision errors though, but I that will be smaller and more insignificant the larger the term is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help!

```
n = NUMBER_OF_TERMS
x = VALUE_OF_X
m = -1
sum = x # Final sum

def fact(i):
    f = 1
    while i >= 1:
        f = f * i
        i = i - 1
    return f

for i in range(1, n):
    r = 2 * i + 1
    a = pow (x , r)
    term = a * m / fact(r);
    sum = sum + term;
    m = m * (-1)
```

Comment: nested loop is not allowed.